# Extract text information from PDF files with different layouts - machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network, nlp, computer-vision

I need assistance with a ML project I am currently trying to create.

I receive a lot of invoices from a lot of different suppliers - all in their own unique layout. I need to extract **3** key elements from the invoices. These **3** elements are all located in a table/line items for all the invoices.

The **3** elements are:

- **1**: Tariff number (digit)
- **2**: Quantity (always a digit)
- **3**: Total line amount (monetary value)

Please refer to below screenshot, where I have marked these field on a sample invoice.

[image]

I started this project with a template approach, based on *regular expressions*. This, however, was not scaleable at all and I ended up with tons of different rules.

I am hoping that machine learning can help me here - or maybe a hybrid solution?

## The common denominator

In **all** of my invoices, despite of the different layouts, each line item will **always** consist of one **tariff number**. This tariff number is always 8 digits, and is always formatted in one the ways like below:

- xxxxxxxx
- xxxx.xxxx
- xx.xx.xx.xx

(Where "x" is a digit from 0 - 9).

**Further**, as you can see on the invoice there is both a Unit Price and a Total Amount per line. The amount I will need is **always** the highest for each line.

## The output

For each invoice like the one above, I need the output for each line. This could for example be something like this:

```
{
    "line":"0",
    "tariff":"85444290",
    "quantity":"3",
    "amount":"258.93"
},
{
    "line":"1",
    "tariff":"85444290",
    "quantity":"4",
    "amount":"548.32"
},
{
    "line":"2",
    "tariff":"76109090",
    "quantity":"5",
    "amount":"412.30"
}
```

## Where to go from here?

I am not sure of what I am looking to do falls under machine learning and if so, under which category. Is it computer vision? NLP? Named Entity Recognition?

My initial thought was to:

1. Convert the invoice to text. (The invoices are all in textable PDFs, so I can use something like `pdftotext` to get the exact textual values)
2. Create custom **named entities** for `quantity`, `tariff` and `amount`
3. Export the found entities.

However, I feel like I might be missing something.

**Can anyone assist me in the right direction?**

## Edit:

Please see below for a few more examples of how an invoice table section can look like:

Sample invoice #2
[image]

Sample invoice #3
[image]

## Edit 2:

Please see below for the three sample images, **without** the borders/bounding boxes:

Image 1:
[image: Sample 1 without bbox]

Image 2:
[image: Sample 2 without bbox]

Image 3:
[image: Sample 3 without bbox]

Comment: Can you show some more examples of the input PDFs to see how much variation there actually is? (=how flexible the solution shall be)

Comment: @sjaustirni Just added two more! I believe the biggest variation between the supplier invoices is how the table layout is (and subsequently the line items, and how the specific text is formatted)

Comment: Perfect! Given these examples, I would probably convert the pdf to text and try to pair the values in there with the the preceding label (e.g. `Tariff No.:` or `$`) or the column it belongs to (here it may help you to save the spatial information of the letters, if any OCR tool does that). I believe you don't need to go into the machine learning with this problem (apart from the pre-made OCR), nor NLP (it is not natural language). However, without seeing how well do these tools work with your data, we can only speculate what is the next step and what is necessary :D

Comment: @sjaustirni wouldn’t that end in the same thing that I am already doing, which is not scaleable? (Template based/regex approach).

Comment: Can't you extract the table itself from the pdf to a datastructure, and then process the columns? May be you can use tabula-py to do this, and then get the quantity and the total directly, and with some regex, the tariff

Comment: Can you add the original input images without the color highlighted boxed? I think I have a solution using OpenCV and Pytesseract OCR. The idea is to remove table grid lines `->` Otsu's threshold `->` merge horizontal text contours `->` find contours and filter from top-to-bottom `->` bitwise-and contour section with input image `->` OCR and filter for contents

Comment: @nathancy I have just added the three sample images without the highlighted boxes. Please note I also have these in a (text) PDF format if that helps. I appreciate your help!

Comment: When you say "I started this project with a template approach, based on regular expressions", does that mean that you have access to the PDF itself? Because if so, you very likely don't need ML, you just need to fit each PDF type in a set of RegEx rules.

Comment: @nathancy any chance you had success with your method? Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: @oliverbj yes I have a potential solution that works for the 1st image but it gives mixed results when trying on the 2nd and 3rd image. Unfortunately, its not as robust since the layout of the invoices are all different.

Comment: @nathancy Do you mind sharing your solution? Even if it just works for the first, I would love to see how you’ve approached the problem

Comment: @oliverbj I've added the solution, hope it helps!

Comment: Although a bit late, but might be helpful to others. You may try www.algodocs.com, which is free for up to 50 pages.

Comment: @Zhavat I think the point is to be able to create this on one's own

Answer (score 10):

Here's an attempt using OpenCV, the idea is:

1. **Obtain binary image.** We load the image, enlarge using
   [`imutils.resize`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing) to help obtain better OCR results (see [Tesseract improve quality](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)), convert to grayscale, then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image (1-channel).
2. **Remove table grid lines.** We create a [horizontal and vertical kernels](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then perform [morphological operations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to combine adjacent text contours into a single contour. The idea is to extract a ROI row as one piece to OCR.
3. **Extract row ROIs.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then sort from top-to-bottom using [`imutils.contours.sort_contours`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7). This ensures that we iterate through each row in the correct order. From here we iterate through the contours, extract the row ROI using Numpy slicing, OCR using [Pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), then parse the data.

---

Here's the visualization of each step:

Input image

[image]

Binary image

[image]

Morph close

[image]

Visualization of iterating through each row

[image]

Extracted row ROIs

[image]
[image]
[image]

Output invoice data result:

```
{'line': '0', 'tariff': '85444290', 'quantity': '3', 'amount': '258.93'}
{'line': '1', 'tariff': '85444290', 'quantity': '4', 'amount': '548.32'}
{'line': '2', 'tariff': '76109090', 'quantity': '5', 'amount': '412.30'}
```

Unfortunately, I get mixed results when trying on the 2nd and 3rd image. This method does not produce great results on the other images since the layout of the invoices are all different. However, this approach shows that it's possible to use traditional image processing techniques to extract the invoice information with the assumption that you have a fixed invoice layout.

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from imutils import contours
import imutils

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image, enlarge, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=1000)
height, width = image.shape[:2]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Morph close to combine adjacent contours into a single contour
invoice_data = []
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (85,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find contours, sort from top-to-bottom
# Iterate through contours, extract row ROI, OCR, and parse data
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")

row = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, 0:width]
    ROI = cv2.GaussianBlur(ROI, (3,3), 0)
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
    parsed = [word.lower() for word in data.split()] 
    if 'tariff' in parsed or 'number' in parsed:
        row_data = {}
        row_data['line'] = str(row)
        row_data['tariff'] = parsed[-1]
        row_data['quantity'] = parsed[2]
        row_data['amount'] = str(max(parsed[10], parsed[11]))
        row += 1

        print(row_data)
        invoice_data.append(row_data)
        
        # Visualize row extraction
        '''
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (0, y), (width, y + h), (255,255,255), -1)
        display_row = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

        cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
        cv2.imshow('display_row', display_row)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        '''
print(invoice_data)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you @nathancy! While this answer is not a generic solution for all my posted invoices, I still think it's the closest I've seen anyone come - and this is just using OpenCV. Very cool and your code example taught me a lot! Again, thank you for taking your time posting this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on a similar problem in the logistics industry and trust me when I say these document tables come in myriad layouts. Numerous companies that have somewhat solved and are improving on this problem are mentioned as under

- Leaders: ABBYY, AntWorks, Kofax, and WorkFusion
- Major Contenders: Automation Anywhere, Celaton, Datamatics, EdgeVerve, Extract Systems, Hyland, Hyperscience, Infrrd, and Parascript
- Aspirants: Ikarus, Rossum, Shipmnts(Alex), Amazon(Textract), Docsumo, Docparser, Aidock

The category I would like to put this problem under would be **multi-modal learning**, because both textual and image modalities contribute a good deal in this problem. Though OCR tokens play a vital role in attribute-value classification, their **position on the page, spacing and inter-character distances** hold as very important features in detecting table, row and column boundaries. The problem gets all the more interesting when rows break across pages, or some columns carry non-empty values.

While the academic world and conferences uses the term **Intelligent Document Processing**, in general for extracting both singular fields and tabular data. The former is more known by attribute-value classification and the latter is famous by table extraction or repeated-structure extraction, in research literature.

In our foray in processing these semi-structured documents over the 3 years, I feel that achieving both **accuracy and scalability** is a long and arduous journey. The solutions that offer scalability / 'template free' approach do have annotated corpus of semi-structured business documents in the order of tens of thousand, if not millions. Though this approach is a scalable solution, it's as good as the documents it has been trained on. If your documents hail from the logistics or insurance sector, which are known for their complex layouts, and need to be super-accurate owing to the compliance procedures, a 'template-based' solution would be the panacea to your ills. It is guaranteed to give more accuracy.

If you need links to existing research, do mention in the comments below and I'ld be happy to share them.

Also, I would recommend using pdfparser[1](https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser) over pdf2text or pdfminer because the former gives character level information in digital files at significantly better performance.

Would be happy to incorporate any feedback, as this is my first answer here.

Comment: If you are looking for an open source repo, https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data could be a good starting point

Comment: SAHANI  - Gone Through the Github repository, want to know where the input file path has been mentioned in the hole folder. Please guide me through this .

Comment: @manish It's in the end of the section Usage https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data#usage

from invoice2data import extract_data
result = extract_data('path/to/my/file.pdf')

Comment: Have created a separate file as suggested-installed the library using pip- Import the library - Tried to extract the data as suggested but it seems to be not working, Error - ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_data'

Comment: @Manish I'm assuming you wrote this ----> from invoice2data import extract_data  and not just       import extract_data. It's working in my case